# Ruby variables and pointers

Tags: ruby

I am practicing with different design patterns in Ruby and am trying to figure out the innards of Ruby. Right now I am practicing with Proxy patterns. If I have my main object:

```
class BankAccount
  attr_reader :balance

  def initialize(starting_balance = 0)
    @balance = starting_balance
  end

  def deposit(amount)
    @balance += amount
  end

  # other code
end
```

And my Proxy object:

```
class BankAccountProxy

  def initialize(real_object)
    @real_object = real_object
  end

  def balance
    @real_object.balance
  end

  def deposit(amount)
    @real_object.deposit(amount)
  end

  # other code
end
```

And I initialize the main and proxy object:

```
main = BankAccount.new(100)
proxy = BankAccountProxy.new(main)
```

Does Ruby make a copy of the main object within the proxy object, and therefore take up memory OR does Ruby simply point to main object from the proxy, and therefore not take up additional space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called "references". Ruby will not make a copy of `main` here. Or anywhere else. It's always references. If you need a copy, you do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I expected but just wanted to make sure. Now to figure out how to test this in irb :). I will give you the check once the timer expires.

Comment: Technically an "object reference", which is a fancy form of pointer.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thankfully! It's just important to note that object references and traditional references are different. Assigning to an argument doesn't change the value, which is an object reference, that was passed in. It gets kind of complicated due to semantics. If people expect Ruby's object references to behave like references in C++ they're in for a surprise.

Comment: @tadman: ah yes, of course, "java-like references", not "C-like references"

Answer (score 1):

Reference to that object. "Immediate values" are just integer and symbols in Ruby.

Comment: And even those are references too :)

Comment: Well, yes, in the sense you can send messages to them

Comment: Thanks Ursus. Make sense. But Sergio beat you to the punch :)

Comment: @Ursus: yes, and all other senses too. It's just that they have no state, which you can modify.

Comment: They are usually not implemented as pointers, but you can't tell because a) pointer referencing and dereferencing is always implicit and automatic in Ruby, so you can't tell whether Ruby dereferenced a pointer for you or not, and b) they are purely immutable, so you wouldn't be able to tell whether you have shared references or copied value objects. So, in short, you may treat objects *always* as pointers, even though some of them actually aren't for performance reasons.